# Draw an always centered overlay on MapView in Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I would like to draw an always centered image overlay in MapView in Android, like a targeting reticle

The way that I am going to approach it is to use the onTouchEvent of Overlay and the
MotionEvent.Move to move the location of the overlay around.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to accomplish this with a RelativeLayout that contains a MapView and an ImageView for your centered image.  Here's some sample XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/google_maps"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="@string/maps_key"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:src="@drawable/mapcenter"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will center your image and cut down on any processing that would otherwise be needed to center/keep the image centered.  There is of course other ways to do this with an OverlayItem, let me know if the XML approach doesn't work and I'll post an Overlay Example.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out, then I can then pass the getcenter back to the ImageView so that the image will know where I am actually centered, will give it ago once I get home.

Comment: kaizenx, if you want to get the center point of the map, then you'll have to use the mapView.getMapCenter() method.